# IP address must be specified?

Tags: python, python-2.7, ip-address, ping

Heres my code running in python 2.7 on windows 10

```
import os

with open('test.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
         response = os.system("ping -c 1" + line)
         if response == 0:
                 print(line, "is up!")
         else:
                 print(line, "is down!")
```

The test.txt file contains some random IP's, the code runs but when it does it give out the message the the IP address must be specified. My problem is I don't know how to do that within the script. When I use the regular command promt and do ping -c 1 google.com it runs through but reading it from the text file with the above python script that same google.com needs to be specified.

Q1: What does it mean to have the ip specified and how would I do it?

Q2: Should I write my code in a diffrent manner importing a different module?

Comment: Take a look at your indentation in the `for` loop. (hint: there is none :) ). The same goes for the conditional `if` statement.

Comment: ~~First of all, have you tried just having it print out the contents of "line"? You'll get a better idea of where the breakdown is.~~(pretend it's stricken-through) Yeah, do that ^

Comment: Yes I tried just printing line and it gives them out individually with some space between. I also fixed the indentation here I have it right in my code just not right on here.

Comment: If a line in your file contains `google.com`, the resulting command you try to execute is `ping -c 1google.com`.  Note the lack of a space compared to your manual command - the address is being interpreted as part of the argument to the `-c` option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import os

with open('test.txt') as f:

 for line in f:

  response = os.system("ping -c 1 " + line.strip())

  if response == 0:

   print(line, "is up!")

  else:

   print(line, "is down!")
```

Strip the newline off the end of the records from the file and add a space in the ping command.

Comment: Ah looking at all the iterations of my code I see I started typing with out the space thank you so much.